# Is there a subnet calculator that computes the *complement* of a subnet?

Tags: networking, subnet

There are plenty of online subnet calculators, but what I sometimes need is one that produces a list of CIDRs that form the **complement** of a given subnet (`my-cidr`) in an address universe. Let's call it a **complementary subnet calculator**. The reason for such a need is that some network resources require me to input all the CIDRs **except** a `my-cidr`.

For example, suppose I have a universe of IP addresses = `10.1.0.0/16`. Within that universe, I allocate `my-cidr` = `10.1.8.0/24` to something. Now, I want to calculate the list of CIDRs that form **the rest of** the universe, i.e., a list like this:

- `10.1.0.0/21`  (`10.1.[0-7].*`)
- ## Skipping my-cidr (`10.1.8.*`) here.
- `10.1.9.0/24` (`10.1.9.*`)
- `10.1.10.0/23` (`10.1.[10-11].*`)
- `10.1.12.0/22` (`10.1.[12-15].*`)
- ...

I Googled and can't find such a calculator. What would be a proper name (and keyword search) for such a kind of calculator, if it already exists?

The closest I can find is the following. It still requires a lot of manual fiddling on my part (clicking the `Divide` link many times) to get to the result:

- https://www.davidc.net/sites/default/subnets/subnets.html?network=10.1.0.0&mask=16&division=17.fd100

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and couldn't find anything online. So I wrote [bitlug](https://www.bitlug.com). You can try it and see if it helps. You might still need to click around a bit depending on what you are after.

In your example, you would put in `10.1.8.0/24` and it will give you the rest of the universe. I will mention if you put in something like `10.1.8.0/16`, it will give you the `/21`'s under the `/16` because `10.1.8.0/21` is the largest subnet of that `/16`. If you wanted the `/24`s locked under a `/16` bit boundary, you would use `10.1.9.0/16` as the starting point. The size of the box changes as you move off the bit boundary. This will make more sense once you play around with it.  It does IPv6 too, which is what I was after.

Comment: Thanks! It seems your tool solves a different problem. Entering `10.1.8.0/24` doesn't produce the answers in my example, e.g., it doesn't produce `10.1.0.0/21`. Your tool produces siblings of the **same** size, but your tool doesn't summarize the siblings into a bigger CIDR whenever possible. In my example, the complement contains subnet summaries like `10.1.0.0/21` rather than siblings of the same size (like `10.1.7.0/24` in your tool which is a portion of the summarized CIDR `10.1.0.0/21`). Perhaps a feature enhancement can be to display summarized sibling CIDRs on another row?